# Underlined Text: Indent on left and right side

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to modify the options for underlined text to have offset on the left and right side, like this:
[image]

For the example above i used the paragrahlines options and add linebreaks.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this with a character-style or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use Paragraph Rules instead of Underline and you can see some settings below to make this work. One problem however, Paragraph Rules only apply to the first line of a paragraph so to make it work you need to manually enter line breaks after each line, basicly turning each line into a paragraph.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I know this workaround, but it is not appropriate to use this with a lot of text. Any other Ideas?

Comment: I dont see any other way but others might so good luck with this :)